# Export commands works in interactive mode, but produces error message in script

Tags: bash, shell-script, qsub

I need to export an environmental variable to run a program. I am able to successfully do that in interactive mode. However, when I try to export an environmental variable as part of a bash shell script, I get this error message:

export: Command not found.

In interactive mode, when I type in the following command, it works.

```
export GT_DIR=/cluster/home/SD/
```

But when I include the export command as part of the shell script, it does not work. I.e.,

```
#!/bin/bash

export GT_DIR=/cluster/home/SD/
```

I get the error message:

```
export: Command not found.
```

When I type in `echo $SHELL`, I get

```
/bin/bash
```

Why  is the export command working in interactive mode but not when I try to submit it as a script?

Comment: what do you get if you do 'type export' in shell, export is a builtin command in bash

Comment: you need to `source somethingthatexportsvariables` so the command is run within the current process. running a different script will only change the environment in that script, which then exits.

Comment: How do you run your script?

Comment: `export: Command not found.` is exactly the error message that a `csh` outputs.

Comment: @rAlen when I do type export, I get this: export is a shell builtin

Comment: @thrig not sure I quite follow what I need to do here

Comment: @Cyrus I run my script with #!/bin/bash as the shebang. Does that not ensure that bash is used instead of csh?

Comment: see Cyrus comment, it seems you script is being started with csh and not bash, how are you running the script, which command do you use to start it, not the shebang in the script, but exact command you use to start the script?

Comment: I'm using qsub script.sh to start it

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42637131/qsub-is-executing-my-bash-script-in-csh-despite-shebang you are starting it in csh it seems, try using qsub shell_sub -S /bin/bash as mentioned there

Comment: @ralen thanks very much for your help. I tried qsub script.sh -S /bin/bash but the shell was still /bin/csh. I also tried qsub script.sh -b y /bin/bash but it still ran as /bin/csh. It looks like the shell_start_mode is posix_compliant rather than unix_behavior so the shebang is being ignored. Any thoughts on how to get around this (other than having to ask my administrator to change the question settings)?

Answer (score -2):

It worked once I added `-S /bin/bash` to the shell script rather than as `qsub -S /bin/bash`